# Do option recovery skills function while options are active?

Tags: gundam-breaker-3

I'm working on making a funnel-focused build, so I'm essentially at the center of a horde of flying laser pirahnas.  With guns.  I'd prefer to just run through, murdering everything without requiring anything but activating my funnels.

Funnels are generally "option" items.  There are a couple abilities you can get that refill option gauges, as it were, such as option recovery on kill, or on break.  If these function while the options are active, I could theoretically build a permanently deployed funnel build, just requiring more enemies to feed the horde.  My observations have been inconclusive; options gauges deplete while they're active, but it's tough to keep an eye on an option gauge, and still keep track of everything around you.  Is it possible to keep those options out permanently?